# React - How to export a pure stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, export

How can I export a stateless pure dumb component?

If I use class this works:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Header extends Component {
    render(){
        return <pre>Header</pre>
    }
}
```

However if I use a pure function I cannot get it to work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default const Header = () => {
    return <pre>Header</pre>
}
```

Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

ES6 doesn't allow `export default const`. You must declare the constant first then export it:

```
const Header = () => {
  return <pre>Header</pre>
};
export default Header;
```

This constraint exists to avoid writting `export default a, b, c;` that is forbidden: only one variable can be exported as default

Answer (score 51):

Just as a side note. You could technically `export default` without declaring a variable first.

```
export default () => (
  <pre>Header</pre>
)
```

Comment: The only downside being that components exported in this way will appear as `Unknown` in chrome's React devtools.

Comment: how do you import a function declared like this?

Comment: @DanielThompson you can import it like so: `import YourComponent from './path/to/component'`

Replace the path with the actual path to the component. The import name for the default export can be anything you'd like, I've chosen `YourComponent` in this example.

Answer (score 25):

### you can do it in two ways

1. 

```js
const ComponentA = props => {
  return <div>{props.header}</div>;
};

export default ComponentA;
```

2)

```js
export const ComponentA = props => {
  return <div>{props.header}</div>;
};
```

if we use `default` to export then we import like this

```
import ComponentA from '../shared/componentA'
```

if we don't use `default` to export then we import like this

```
import { ComponentA } from '../shared/componentA'
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also use a function declaration instead of assignment:

```
export default function Header() {
    return <pre>Header</pre>
}
```

In your example, you already use curly brackets and `return` so this is apparently matching with your needs with no compromise.

Comment: This was my preferred approach until Typescript. With TS, it is (unfortunately) useful to return to the `const` arrow function approach for declaring property types: `const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = () => {}`.

Comment: @Trevor, genuine question, I am still making my first steps with TS: why not just `export default function MyComponent(props: MyComponentProps) {}` as opposed to using `const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = () => {}` ?

Comment: @gmagno, if you take a look at the definition of FC/FunctionComponent, you'll see it does a few more things for you: 1) return type of `ReactElement | null`, 2) adds `children` to the properties, 3) adds other members to the FC like `propTypes` and `defaultProps`.

Answer (score 0):

`export default const` is not supported.

You can do something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {
    render(){
        return <pre>Header</pre>
    }
}

export default Header;
```