# useStaticQuery: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: typescript, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to get values via `useStaticQuery` from gatsby-config.js.
My codes are the followings.

Could anyone have any ideas to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance

repo
https://github.com/koji/portfolio

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "gatsby": "^2.13.28",
    "gatsby-link": "^2.2.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.1.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.2",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.8",
    "gatsby-source-instagram-all": "^2.0.5",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack": "^4.36.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "@types/react-helmet-async": "^1.0.0",
    "env-cmd": "^9.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-tslint": "^0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.4",
    "tslint-react": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
```

siteMetadata.ts

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
export const useSiteMetadata = () => {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            author
          }
        }
      }
    `);
  return site.siteMetadata.title;
};
```

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useSiteMetadata } from 'siteMetadata'


export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {title} = useSiteMetadata();
    return (
        <h1>
          <Link className={headerStyles.title} to="/">
            {title}
          </Link>
        </h1>
    )
  }
}
```

gatsby-config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "page title",
    author: "me"
  }
}
```

Comment: `useSiteMetadata` is a function, you have to call it to get the value it returns (that is, write `useSiteMetadata()`. **Also**, it's not an ordinary function, it's a React hook which means you can call it only from inside functional react component, during render time. Calling it to initialize some variable in the module scope just will not work.

Comment: Now the error is because the hook can't be used in class components. It's for functional components only, you need to [rewrite your component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695189/react-how-to-export-a-pure-stateless-component) to be something like `const Header: React.FC = () => (<h1>... </h1>); export default Header;`

Comment: @artem Thank you very much for your help. You made my day.
Finally It works

Answer (score 3):

the first letter in the name of the component not capitalized and it causing this problem;

and `useStaticQuery` doesn't work like that, you need to render the component's children that depend on this query inside the component you use it there;

the component UseSiteMetadata will be :

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
export const useSiteMetadata = () => {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            author
          }
        }
      }
    `);
  return (
        <h1>
          <Link className={headerStyles.title} to="/">
            {site.siteMetadata.title}
          </Link>
        </h1>
  );
```

and the `Header` will be :

```
import * as React from "react";
import { UseSiteMetadata } from 'siteMetadata'


export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<UseSiteMetadata /> )
  }
}
```

Comment: You are adding a component not a hook here.  Please don't use hooks like components.  Please see the react docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but others might run into it too.

The problem is that you are returning the string found in title in the useSiteMetadata hook but then destructing it in the Header component.

I think that you meant to return an object from the hook:

```
return {title: site.siteMetadata.title};
```

Or more consistent with the hook name:

```
return site.siteMetadata;
```

Please do not capitalize hooks nor use them like components as suggested in other answers.  See the react docs to find out why.